# On the origin and usage of 'sight unseen'

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english

The expression ***[sight unseen](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sight+unseen)***  means:

> - Without having viewed the object in question, as in *He bought the horse sight unseen.*

The *American Heritage Dictionary* notes that:

> - This seeming oxymoron (how can a sight, which means something seen, be not seen?) dates from the late 1800s.

According to *Grammarphobia*:

> - *The Oxford English Dictionary* says “[sight unseen](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/05/out-of-sight.html)” is an American expression for “without inspection” and dates from the 1890s. The OED’s earliest citation, from 1892, is in Dialect Notes, a journal of the American Dialect Society: “To trade knives sight unseen is to swap without seeing each other’s knife.”

There appear to be earlier usages of the expression as in [*A History of American Mannfactores from 1608 to 1860*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XHqw1gVVJfoC&pg=PA429&dq=%22sight%20unseen%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBmoVChMIt8ublc2rxwIVhFUUCh2cIgOV#v=onepage&q=%22sight%20unseen%22&f=false),  published in 1866 :

> - The price of a cow and calf, he says, was 50s., ***" sight unseen, be she big or little, they are never very curious to examine that point."***

My questions:

1. What is the origin and first usage of this idiomatic expression?
2. What are other common idiomatic expressions (AmE or BrE) that convey the same meaning?

Comment: Intriguing. From what I can make out, your "1866" example was actually written by [John Clayton](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4247425?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) around 1672. While serving as "rector of James Town Parish ... in the Colonies", in correspondence with the famous Irish/British scientist [Robert Boyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Boyle). Clayton later returned to live in England, so it's not obvious to me that justifies calling the usage "originally U.S.".

Comment: Same meaning: He bought a horse **in blind** *or* He spent a lot of money for the **blind** acquisition of the horse.

Comment: I don’t understand why anyone would think this an oxymoron: makes perfect sense. For example, sightseers in a hurry might well leave some sight unseen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is documentation that your 1866 example in your post is actually from 1694 or earlier, in a description "of the Beasts of Virginia," by Mr. John Clayton.

[From Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=OMNeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA124-IA1&dq=%22sight+unseen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6wEwCDgKahUKEwjQoOHGz7zHAhXE7R4KHYBVATY#v=onepage&q=%22sight%20unseen%22&f=false), *Philsophical Transactions*, vol XVIII, London.

> The Common Rate of a Cow and Calf, is 50 s. sight unseen, be she big or little, they are never very Curious to Examine that Point.

There is a very similar expression that means the same thing, and which seems much more common in the 18th century: *unsight, unseen*. The earliest I can find this expression in [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=qaNeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22unsight+unseen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI4pu6iNe8xwIVxFc-Ch08rQ30#v=onepage&q=%22unsight%20unseen%22&f=false) is from 1694, in *Hudibras* by Samuel Butler:

> For to subscribe, unsight, unseen,
>   T' an unknown Church Discipline,
>   What is it else, but beforehand,
>   T' ingage, and after understand?

The OED dates *unsight, unseen* (*Obs.*) to 1627:

> a1627   **T. Middleton & W. Rowley** *Old Law* (1656),   Take that at hazard sir... Unsight, unseen, I take 3. to one.
>   1632   **R. Brome** *Northern Lasse*, I would I had his Neece unsight and unseen I faith for her monies sake.

So I would conjecture that *sight unseen* originated from an alteration of *unsight unseen*. This alteration makes some sense, and replaces the word *unsight*, which the OED says is used as an adjective only in that expression. The OED's guess at the etymology of *unsight, unseen* is that it is a corrupted or dialect version of *unsighted, unseen*. But they attach a question mark to this etymology, so they aren't very sure about this.

Comment: So it is actually much older than what OED says, and  probably of BrE origin.

Comment: @Josh61: Since Mr. John Clayton spent a few years in Virginia (1684-1686), when he was minister at Jamestown), I would say that the place of origin is still uncertain.

Comment: And [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsight+unseen%2Csight+unseen&year_start=1750&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunsight%20unseen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csight%20unseen%3B%2Cc0) is an interesting Google Ngram showing the replacement of *unsight unseen* with *sight unseen* in American English. The 1694 example may be just an isolated occurrence. And British English presumably adopted *sight unseen* from the U.S., since its use in the U.K. increases substantially later.

Answer (score -1):

"Sight Unseen" originated from when guns were used on a daily basis, when a gun was shot without looking at the gun's sight. i.e. Shooting from the hip or in a fashion where the sights are not used.
Example: The cowboy hit the target sight unseen.